# JS new set, remove duplicates case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = ['verdana', 'Verdana', 2, 4, 2, 8, 7, 3, 6];
result =  Array.from(new Set(arr));

console.log(arr);
console.log(result);
```

i want to remove any duplicates case-insensitive
so the expected result should be

> ['Verdana', 2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6]

but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Define `does not seem to work` please, because it does work for me.

Comment: it doesn't remove Verdana

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JavaScript comparator is case sensitive. For strings you may need to clean up the data first:

```
var arr = ['verdana', 'Verdana', 2, 4, 2, 8, 7, 3, 6]
  .map(x => typeof x === 'string' ? x.toLowerCase() : x);
result =  Array.from(new Set(arr));
// produces ["verdana", 2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6];
```

---

Alternatively, you may use `reduce()` with a custom nested comparing logic. The implementation below *compares the items ignoring the case*, but for "equal" strings it picks the first occurrence, regardless what its "casing" is:

```
'verdana', 'Moma', 'MOMA', 'Verdana', 2, 4, 2, 8, 7, 3, 6]
  .reduce((result, element) => {
    var normalize = x => typeof x === 'string' ? x.toLowerCase() : x;

    var normalizedElement = normalize(element);
    if (result.every(otherElement => normalize(otherElement) !== normalizedElement))
      result.push(element);

    return result;
  }, []);
// Produces ["verdana", "Moma", 2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6]
```

Comment: but what if... I want I have one entry like "MoMa"...and I don't want to make it lowercase?

Comment: @Francesco this is way trickier. I would use something different, not `Set`. Need to think about it. Ideally, `Set` should receive a `equality` function, but I double checked with the MDN -- and don't see anything that would allow us to tweak `Set`'s behavior.

Comment: @Francesco also, if your array was `['MoMa', 'MOMA', 'moma', 'moMA']`, how would one guess what will be remain in the list, and what would go away?

Comment: @Francesco see my updated answer with sample code for "MoMa" situation. Hope, it helps.

Comment: yeah, I agree is too much to ask, unless there is a predefined rule to keep "MoMa" instead of other cases...+1

Comment: Your second function runs in O(n^2) time. You could it improve it to O(n) by using a hash.

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = ['verdana', 'Verdana', 2, 4, 2, 8, 7, 3, 6];

function getUniqueValuesWithCase(arr, caseSensitive){
    let temp = [];
    return [...new Set(caseSensitive ? arr : arr.filter(x => {
        let _x = typeof x === 'string' ? x.toLowerCase() : x;
        if(temp.indexOf(_x) === -1){
            temp.push(_x)
            return x;
        }
    }))];
}
getUniqueValuesWithCase(arr, false); // ["verdana", 2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6]
getUniqueValuesWithCase(arr, true);  // ["verdana", "Verdana", 2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` after converting the string elements to `uppercase`.Here `...` is spread operator

```js
var arr = ['verdana', 'Verdana', 2, 4, 2, 8, 7, 3, 6];

var result = arr.map(function(item) {
  return typeof item === "string" ? item.toString().toUpperCase() : item
})

result = [...new Set(result)];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `.toString()` is redundand if it's known that `typeof item === 'string'`. _Spread operator_ is for good though!

Comment: Doesn't seem to match the output that is asked for (Verdana and not VERDANA)